# Google Cloud Storage with get_serving_url

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to serve image files on Google Cloud Storage with Images API `get_serving_url`.
Can `get_serving_url` accept files on Google Cloud Storage?

I tried:

```
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import images
bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/bucket/object')
url = images.get_serving_url(bkey)
```

A error `InvalidBlobKeyError` occured on `get_serving_url` in production environment.

Comment: this is a great question: I need to get out of blobstore, but continue to use the feature of putting =sXXX to resize images on the fly!

Comment: Since 1.7.0, We are going to be able to use get_serving_url() for Google Cloud Storage buckets.

Comment: blobstore is no longer needed, one can just use `images.get_serving_url(None, filename='/gs/<bucket>/<object>'))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everybody would love that, and since 1.7.0 version it is possible!

You can use the `get_serving_url()` for Google Cloud Storage buckets.

Comment: Correct - get_serving_url is not support in the current release for Google Storage objects. Stay tuned.

Comment: @StuartLangley what do you mean?! It's coming soon?! Can't wait... or maybe instead of waiting..  I'm just going to start filling the Storage with some images :)

Comment: I read SDK, there are codes for Google Storage, but they does not work on dev_appserver too. I think it will be support.

Comment: @najeira for now it's not working.. but I will update my answer once it will.. Stuart Langley works for Google App Engine and Google Storage and he agrees :)

Comment: In RELEASE_NOTES of 1.7.0 prerelease, `You can now use get_serving_url() and delete_serving_url() for Google Cloud Storage buckets.`.

Comment: @najeira I will update my answer as soon as it's officially announced on the blog or something!! But this is great news..

Comment: Ok this is now live. Have Fun.

Comment: @StuartLangley Yeeeap!! Just noticed it when I tried to update an app and it screamed: Latest SDK: api_versions: ['1'] release: 1.7.0

Comment: @StuartLangley Is it possible to get the get_serving_url() without using Google App Engine at all?

Answer (score 5):

Just as of GAE 1.6.5, the images.Image class constructor can take as an argument a GCS file name, e.g.

```
 img = images.Image(filename='/gs/bucket/object')
```

You can then execute transforms on that object and serve it up, etc.

Comment: I know images API can transform GCS files. But I want to GCS to serve files directly with resizing and cropping same as blobstore.

Comment: hey, any idea how to get the serving url for a file from gcs WITHOUT using a blobkey, hence the example reported in this answer without any other data?