# Displaying an image with Google Cloud Storage client library on dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to display an image with the Google Cloud Storage client library on the dev server.  I figured out how to upload a photo.  But not sure how to get it to display while using Flask.

If I deploy to App Engine, I can get the images to display if I link directly to them.  Like if I put the following in the template:

```
<img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/foo/{{ userid }}.jpg">
```

But that doesn't work on the dev server, because the uploads aren't actually going up to App Engine.  So I was wondering how I can read the objects using the client library and display them in Flask.

The following code works for the POST (upload) part.  But on the GET, I'm not sure where to go.  To get the image to put on the template.  I was hoping to just be able to use a URL.

```
BUCKET = 'foo'

def account():
    if request.method == "GET":
        #not sure how to get the image to then display on the template
        filename = "/".join(['', BUCKET, g.user.key.id()])
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
        return render_template('users/account.html')
    else:
        image = request.files.get('file', None)
        filename = "/".join(['', BUCKET, g.user.key.id()])
        write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
        with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type=image.mimetype, 
                            retry_params=write_retry_params) as imageFile:
            image.save(imageFile)
        return redirect(url_for("users.account"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `get_serving_url`, which now works with Google Cloud Storage. It should also work when using the dev server.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10415583/624900) for more information.

Comment: I see.  I saw that question and saw the blobstore stuff and ignored it.  Because I thought there was away to just use Google Cloud Storage client library and not have to use blobstore stuff.  But I guess that's not really storing anything in blobstore.  But yeah, thanks!  This worked!